# Different EXPLAIN ANALYZE results for the same query on different servers

Tags: postgresql, index, explain

I have a table named `review` with about 33 million rows.

I have this query:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
(WITH clicker_reviews AS (
  SELECT
    monologue_id
  FROM review
  WHERE
    type = 'CORE'
    AND
    clicker_id = 959
)
  SELECT count(DISTINCT monologue_id) FROM clicker_reviews
)
```

The query itself is slow, at times taking 14-21 seconds for some users. This is too long as its results face the user. Sometimes it times out (using Heroku, where timeout is at 30 sec.)

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` above returns this QUERY PLAN:

```
Aggregate  (cost=7652.94..7652.95 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=14008.525..14008.527 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using review_clicker_id on review  (cost=0.11..7646.08 rows=13730 width=8) (actual time=15.004..13984.806 rows=81612 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (clicker_id = 959)
"        Filter: (type = 'CORE'::review_type)"
        Rows Removed by Filter: 40806
Planning Time: 0.159 ms
Execution Time: 14008.578 ms
```

I'm new to EXPLAIN ANALYZE, but I think getting rid of Filter and, especially, large numbers of "Rows Removed by Filter" is what I want.

So I added a multicolumn index in hope of speeding things up:

```sql
CREATE INDEX "review_clicker_id_type" ON "review" ("clicker_id", "type");
```

## After adding an index

After doing so, things got better locally:

```
Aggregate  (cost=16728.43..16728.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1729.366..1729.397 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using idx_25007_type on review  (cost=0.56..16513.43 rows=86000 width=8) (actual time=4.723..1008.846 rows=81540 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((type = 'CORE'::review_type) AND (clicker_id = 959))
        Heap Fetches: 8986
Planning Time: 19.948 ms
Execution Time: 1729.530 ms
```

It's not fast, but the filter is gone and I don't seem to be running into query times of 10+ seconds.

But, in production, it didn't change the query plan:

```
Aggregate  (cost=7651.48..7651.48 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=67.565..67.566 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using review_clicker_id on review  (cost=0.11..7644.62 rows=13727 width=8) (actual time=0.036..49.510 rows=81612 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (clicker_id = 959)
"        Filter: (type = 'CORE'::review_type)"
        Rows Removed by Filter: 40806
Planning Time: 0.184 ms
Execution Time: 67.608 ms
```

So I'm worried it's still going to be too slow at times.

My questions are:

1. **Am I better off with a "Heap Fetches: 8986" over a "Rows Removed by Filter: 40806" or not?**
2. **Why aren't both Postgres servers returning the same query plan?**

Both servers are running Postgres 13.

---

***EDIT:***

## 2. After running `VACUUM ANALYZE` on both tables

Locally:

```
Aggregate  (cost=4020.07..4020.09 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1436.352..1436.382 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using idx_25007_type on review  (cost=0.56..3805.46 rows=85845 width=8) (actual time=8.319..735.808 rows=81540 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((type = 'CORE'::review_type) AND (clicker_id = 959))
        Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 17.348 ms
Execution Time: 1436.469 ms
```

In production:

```
Aggregate  (cost=2090.65..2090.65 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=21.582..21.583 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using idx_25007_type on review  (cost=0.11..2050.60 rows=80098 width=8) (actual time=0.030..14.087 rows=81756 loops=1)
"        Index Cond: ((type = 'CORE'::review_type) AND (clicker_id = 959))"
        Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.526 ms
Execution Time: 21.626 ms
```

These are the results I'm getting after running VACUUM ANALYZE today.

So I guess I'm OK. I'll just want to keep an eye on Heap Fetches.

---

Details: I don't know if this is related but I'll mention it in case it is...

- When I was still running Postgres 9.6 (until a few days ago), because of issues with slow queries when using `LIMIT 1`, I used a lot of [`ORDER BY` tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27237698/1717535) to speed things up. However, in Postgres 13, they don't help anymore and so I'm rewriting things with CTEs instead (to move the LIMIT 1 "outside".)

Comment: Did you `vacuum analyze` after creating the index?

Comment: The query runs in 67ms in production (so less than one second). The plan locally doesn't use the index you have shown us, but an index that contains all three columns named `idx_25007_type`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name idx_25007_type is a UNIQUE multicolumn index on (type,clicker_id,monologue_id,iteration). I have it both in production and locally.

Comment: @mustaccio The bloat level is the same locally and in production, at 1.3 (`idx_25007_type`) and 1.2 (`review_done_due_monologue_id`) max (and 0.1 to 0.6 for the other indexes on that table.)

Comment: Who said anything about bloat?  Your estimated are way off on prod, and heap fetches pretty high on test.

Comment: So where do I start? The indexes didn't help, the CTE didn't help. What are my options?

Comment: Do the VACUUM ANALYZE on both tables in both databases, and edit the question to include the new plans.  Also turn on track_io_timing first, and do EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) this time.

Comment: @jjanes Thank you. I updated the question. I guess it's OK now.